# open() file does not exists when file actually exists

Tags: c, file, file-exists

I'm writing a simple HTTP server and I'm getting a file does not exists return value when the file does exist

```
printf("%s\n", html_path);
if ((fd = open(html_path, "r")) >= 0){ //file found

  stat(file_name, &st);
  file_size = st.st_size;
  printf("%d\n", file_size);
  while (read(fd, response, RCVBUFSIZE) > 0){

  }
}
else { //file not found
    strcpy(response, "404 File not found\n");
    send(clntSocket, response, 32, 0);
}
```

the print statement is to verify the path and it looks like this:

`/mounts/u-zon-d2/ugrad/kmwe236/HTML/index.html`

note that this path is on a server that we use at our university. it's the path that shows when I command `pwd`

I have confirmed that the file exists. is there something wrong with my path?

Comment: First thing observed: Is it possible that you mix open and fopen?  "r" would fit fopen, for open you would pass O_RDONLY.

Comment: Where did you get `open` function from? If this is supposed to be a system call `open(2)`, then it has different prototype and you should write `open(html_path, O_RDONLY)`. Or maybe you wanted to use `fopen(3)`? Anyway, if it fails it doesn't mean that file doesn't exist: there may be other issues, for example you do not have proper access privileges. Use `strerror(3)` to print the actual cause of error.

Answer (score 2):

There was an error opening the file, but you don't know that it was because the file was not found because you're didn't check the value of `errno`.

In the `else` section, add the following:

```
else { //file not found
    // copy the value of errno since other function calls may change its value
    int err = errno;
    if (err == ENOENT) {
        strcpy(response, "404 File not found\n");
        send(clntSocket, response, 32, 0);
    } else {
        printf("file open failed: error code %d: %s\n", err, strerror(err));
    }
}
```

If the file does not in fact exist you'll handle the error properly.  If not, you'll print an error message that tells you what did happen.

You're also calling `open` incorrectly.  The second parameter is an `int` containing flags.  To open a file for reading, use `O_RDONLY`.

Answer (score 1):

open does not have the 2nd parameter as a string. You using open with the parameters of fopen.
For a webserver fopen, fprintf, fclose is a better choise then more lowlevel open, read, ...

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where you program is executing as it will try to open the path relative from that location. To check use:

```
char cwd[1024];
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
puts(cwd);
```

Then you can concatenate your path using:

```
strncat(cwd, html_path, 100);
```

You may find that you have to go up one directory or something to then find the file you're looking for.

Also note that if you're debugging your program via `gdb` it may execute from a different location from your regular build location which may make it harder to spot bugs.